# writing data to a file using tkinter button commands

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the below code that creates a python GUI using tkinter it presents the user with a few options such as two check boxes and two fill in text fills. I am trying to get the program to create a file that fills in fields in a template when the user clicks the go button. For example if the guest name is charles marriott. I am trying to create a file named charles marriott.html which contains a statement like "welcome %s to the hotel. We see you will be traveling by plane to the hotel." Do I have to create another function to do this and is this even possible to do with Tkinter or do I need to use another library I'm not aware of?

```
from Tkinter import *

    class App:
        def __init__(self, master):
            column0_padx = 24
            row_pady = 36

            #Label 1
            lbl_testcase_exec = Label(master, text="Visiting by Train",
                                      wraplength=100, anchor='w', justify='left')
            lbl_results_cmp = Label(master, text="Visting by Plane",
                                    wraplength=100, justify='left')
            testcase_exec = Checkbutton(master)
            results_cmp = Checkbutton(master)
            tolerance = Entry(master, width=4)
            lbl_analysis = Label(master, text="Guest Name")
            analysis_lib = Entry(master, width=30)

            lbl_testcase_exec.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=20, pady=12, sticky='w')
            lbl_results_cmp.grid(row=0, column=3, pady=12, sticky='w')
            lbl_analysis.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w', padx=column0_padx)
            analysis_lib.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='w')
            testcase_exec.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=20, sticky='w')
            results_cmp.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky='w')
            tolerance.grid(row=1, column=4, padx=20, sticky='w')

            #Label 2
            lbl_ref_analysis = Label(
                master, text="Point of Contact",
                wraplength=150, justify='left', pady=row_pady)
            ref_analysis_lib = Entry(master, width=30)
            lbl_ref_analysis.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='w', padx=column0_padx)
            ref_analysis_lib.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='w')

            # buttons
            bottom_frame = Frame(master)
            bottom_frame.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=3, sticky='w')

            btn_start = Button(bottom_frame, text = "Go", width=7)
            btn_start.pack(side='left')
            btn_commit = Button(bottom_frame, text="Commit", width=7)
            btn_commit.pack(side='left', padx=80)
            btn_exit = Button(bottom_frame, text="Exit", width=7)
            btn_exit.pack(side='left')

    root = Tk()
    root.title("Templates")
    root.minsize(800, 400)
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you know how to write to a file in python? Do you know how to associate a button with a function (command =...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another method to `class App` that creates the file, then associate it with a button click by configuring the button with a `command=self.newmethod`.

Here's a minimal example based on your code:

```
from Tkinter import *

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        column0_padx = 24
        row_pady = 36

        #Label 1
        lbl_testcase_exec = Label(master, text="Visiting by Train",
                                  wraplength=100, anchor='w', justify='left')
        lbl_results_cmp = Label(master, text="Visting by Plane",
                                wraplength=100, justify='left')
        testcase_exec = Checkbutton(master)
        results_cmp = Checkbutton(master)
        tolerance = Entry(master, width=4)
        lbl_analysis = Label(master, text="Guest Name")
        analysis_lib = Entry(master, width=30)

        lbl_testcase_exec.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=20, pady=12, sticky='w')
        lbl_results_cmp.grid(row=0, column=3, pady=12, sticky='w')
        lbl_analysis.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='w', padx=column0_padx)
        analysis_lib.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='w')
        testcase_exec.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=20, sticky='w')
        results_cmp.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky='w')
        tolerance.grid(row=1, column=4, padx=20, sticky='w')

        #Label 2
        lbl_ref_analysis = Label(
            master, text="Point of Contact",
            wraplength=150, justify='left', pady=row_pady)
        ref_analysis_lib = Entry(master, width=30)
        lbl_ref_analysis.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='w', padx=column0_padx)
        ref_analysis_lib.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='w')

        # buttons
        bottom_frame = Frame(master)
        bottom_frame.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=3, sticky='w')

        btn_start = Button(bottom_frame, text = "Go", width=7)
        btn_start.pack(side='left')
        btn_commit = Button(bottom_frame, text="Commit", width=7,
                            command=self.write_file)  # added command=
        btn_commit.pack(side='left', padx=80)
        btn_exit = Button(bottom_frame, text="Exit", width=7)
        btn_exit.pack(side='left')

    # additional method
    def write_file(self):
        """ Write data to file. """
        with open(filename, 'wt') as outf:
            outf.write(...whatever...)
            outf.write(...whatever else...)
               ...

root = Tk()
root.title("Templates")
root.minsize(800, 400)
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```